# What CSS value makes a button-tag being displayed lower than a div-tag?

Tags: html, css

I have used `<div>` for some buttons, but want to change it to `<button>` since that is a bit more convenient.

I did that simple change. To my surprise the `<button>` is displayed some pixels (maybe 10px) below where the `<div>` was placed.

I have tried to look through all CSS values, but I can't see any that has changed. I guess I am missing something...

Anyone has an idea what CSS value I can be missing? (This is in Google Chrome, have not tested in FF at the moment.)

**UPDATE**: It looks the same in FF. (I.e. the `<button>` is placed lower.)
And all computed CSS values are equal in FF.

So, there seem to be some other rule than CSS that is placing the `<button>` lower. Is there some HTML rule that does that, or???

**UPDATE 2**: And everything is border-box, of course...

**UPDATE 3**: Here are all the computed style vaules (from FF):

```
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-duration: 0.65s;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-name: click-wave;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: #CE742B;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #333;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
font-family: RobotoDraft,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 32px;
line-height: 17px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 8px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
min-width: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
text-alignrightwidth: 80px;
```

Comment: Good question, of course, @AlvaroMontoro. I have added all I see in the UI in FF. Though I just realized I did not add all. The list above does not include the "browser styles".

Comment: Are those the computed styles for the `button` or the `div`? We'd need both to compare. The issue would look like some style that affects the `button` in a different way from the `div` (maybe not set by you, but the default browser's value)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: They are for both, they are the same (except for text-align, but that does not matter).

Comment: I've also checked the "browser styles" button in FF and looked through all the values, but I still can't find anything that differs. (Except for border, but I have tried setting `border:none` on the `<button>`. No change in vertical position.)

Comment: I think there's some other style that you may be missing because with the styles provided, I cannot reproduce the issue (see http://jsfiddle.net/96wuzs9w/). Could you provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I noticed padding is something extra in button. setting `padding:0px` and `line-height: <same as height>` fixes the alignment differences between button and div.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, @AlvaroMontoro. I changed it a bit to reflect my code, please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/4tgxxbq5/. The vertical placement difference shows up there.

Comment: That might be a clue, @gp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by taking a look at your jsbin. So strange, when you have consecutive div + button, the `width: 80px` is causing the button to have whacky placement. IDK why that is.

The fix is to add `float: left` and they align properly. Or use div + div || button + button.

Comment: Yes, very strange. Can you please add a link to your version of the fiddle?

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgrzjd9b/. Like I said, all I did was add `float:left;` (remove `float: none;`). Or use div + div || button + button.